# Convert c++ code to python,with operators?

Tags: python, c++, operators

how would i convert the following code to python?

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 50; i++)
```

im not sure the ++ operator exists in python so im having a little bit of a hard time with it.

Comment: 1. Convert this to `while` and then convert it to python. 2. Look at `range()` in python.

Comment: Don't try to convert between languages by replacing the syntax. Understand what the code does, and implement the same thing in the other language.

Answer (score 0):

```
i = 1
while i <= 50:
    # your code here
    i += 1
```

Or

```
for i in range(1, 51):
    pass
```

[`range()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#range)'s upper bound is exclusive.

Answer (score 0):

that i++ is only a way of displaying i = i + 1.. dont hang around it too much if there is other way..

```
i = 1
while i <= 50:
    print(i)
    i += 1 # or i = i + 1 or what ever display that produce the same result
```

Answer (score 0):

First off, what are you trying to accomplish? Are you trying to write a converter? Or do you need help with Python? In any case, to answer your question, in order to do a `for` loop in Python, all you have to do is this:

```py
for i in range(6):
    print(i)
```

As per w3schools documentation, the parameters for the `range()` function are as follows:

`range(start, stop, step)`

With `start` being the start number, stop being the number to end at, and step being the number increase/decrease every iteration.

I'm not too experienced with Python. I'm sure that there is a built-in iterator function that allows you to do some enhanced-for-loop trickery.

Answer (score 0):

This loop begins with `i = 1` and the last iteration is when `i = 50`, so you can reproduce this in Python using:

```
for i in range(1, 51):
    print(i)
```

(if for some reason, you are stuck using Python 2, consider using `xrange` instead of `range`)